# On manifolds with a polytope decomposition

Tags: general-topology, terminology, manifolds, definition, topological-quantum-field-theory

How are *manifolds with a polytope decomposition* defined?

I stumbled upon them when reading about the category of cobordisms with polytope decomposition.
This category is defined as having as objects "oriented, closed one-dimensional manifolds with a polytope decomposition."
I can imagine what they could be, but I don't want to start guessing.

Comment: For 1-dimensional manifolds this would be the same as a CW-complex structure. In higher dimensions, there are several related notions which are all different. But you should add a precise reference to the book/article where you found this notion.